# I need horizontal scroll bar with fixed width and right side checkbox

Tags: css, html5

I need horizontal scroll bar with fixed width and right side check box.

Currently I truncate the text, but I need horizontal scroll without truncate.

Refer my sample page is here:- https://jsfiddle.net/gsk/hxxk53ey/22/

Thanks in advance.